# Auto Scroll with UITableView

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

I'm making an ipad app. In the app I have a UITableView with custom cells that the user can type into. The only problem is that when you press on one of the lower cells, the keyboard comes up and blocks the cell so you can't see it.I'd like it so when you press on the cell that is just above the keyboard, the UITableView scroll up and reveals 1 more cell over and over again so you can see what you're typing. Thanks.

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn4CT.png

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are typing into a uitextfield, implement the textfield delegate methods.

figure out the keyboard height when keyboard is shown.

edit:

This is how I'd go about solving the problem:

Tag each text filed with a unique number (keep a baseConstantInteger, ensure your tags are absolutely unique).

baseConstant could be anything, lets assume `baseConstantInteger = 500;`

for each cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, in your custom cell set the

```
textField.tag = baseConstantInteger+indexPath.row
```

and then

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    int clickedRow = textField.tag - baseConstantInteger;
    [self.theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(indexPath based on clickedRow) atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(theTableView.frame.origin, theTableView.contentSize.width, theTableView.frame.size.height-keyBoardHeight);
                     }
     ];
}
```

and when returned (similar for didEndEditing)

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(theTableView.frame.origin, theTableView.contentSize.width, theTableView.frame.size.height+keyBoardHeight);
                     }
     ];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO/YES;
}
```

ps: baseConstantInteger is just to keep your tags safe. its not absolutely required for this to work.

Comment: I entered the bit about it being a custom cell because the UITextField is in the custom cell... which is in a different view which means i can't access it via the view which the UITableView is in

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, the TextField that I want to access is in another view (flightDetialCell). How can I access the TextField from the view I am currently in?

Thanks heaps

Comment: what do you mean access the textfield? I have no idea about "another view" and "flightDetailCell". You'll have to post more code or clarify your question further